# Android lock screen push notification

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, android-5.0-lollipop, android-4.4-kitkat

How can I send lock screen push notification in Android mobile. My code is

```
mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.gcm_cloud)
            .setContentTitle("Notification")
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
            .setContentText(msg);

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) this.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);

    WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "TAG"); wl.acquire(15000);

    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
```

Comment: This is not a push notification. This will notify you in notificationbar

Comment: this is just sample. its not full code part like access gcm server is other part.

Comment: http://javapapers.com/android/google-cloud-messaging-gcm-for-android-and-push-notifications/    I try this and succeeded but I want lock screen also.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, because:

1. [`Push notifications`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology) are sent from a system to another. You just want a "regular" notification, this has nothing to do with [GCM](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html).
2. Lockscreen notifications are a [Lollipop](http://www.greenbot.com/article/2851690/how-to-make-the-most-of-android-5-0-lollipop-s-new-lock-screen-settings.html) feature and your `android-4.4-kitkat` question tag is a clue.

Comment: Thanks to (or because of) their privacy concern, you have to set a public version through `setPublicVersion` https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setPublicVersion(android.app.Notification) or define its visibility through `setVisibility`

Comment: More on Android 5.0 Notifications: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0.html#Notifications